# ссылки в Twig шаблонизаторе

Tags: twig

Ссылку на нужную страницу средствами  php можно сделать так:

`<li><a href="./index.php?page=rol-razmetki-html">Какую роль играет язык разметки - HTML ?</a></li>`

Как сделать подобную ссылку средствами Twig ?

Comment: В каком смысле сделать так? Если вы вставите эту же строку в twig, то она так же отобразится как если бы вы это вставили в php... В чем именно заключается ваш вопрос?